# relative pronoun and preposition

Tags: relative-pronouns

There are question in my textbook:

> The CDs in that music shop ____ we poked our heads into last week are
>   on sale now.
>
> (A) whose (B) what (C) which (D) where

The answer is (C). I want to know if there is no "into" in the question sentence the answer become "(D) where"?

I mean, is it ok to say "The CDs in that music shop where we poked our heads last week are on sale now."?

Comment: Without **into** the listener will be wondering **what** you poked your heads with? I see nothing wrong with using **where**, and a native AmE speaker would use **in**: **where** we poked our heads **in**

Comment: The most common would probably be **that**. I would use it or *which* more than I would *where*.  *What* might be acceptable in some British English or other dialects, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "where" also means "the place at/in which".

I think the OP can omit "into" and use "where" instead of "which"  in the sentence presented, without any difference in meaning.